# In C++ when we make a function pure virtual in base class then what is the necessity of making the same function virtual again in child class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance, virtual-functions, pure-virtual

I have a function X() declared as PURE VIRTUAL in base class:

```
class Base 
{
public:  
    virtual HRESULT X()=0; // Now it's pure virtual. 
    .......
    };




class Derived_1 : public Base  
  {   
    HRESULT X()   
    {  
    // body of function X() ; full definition given here as per Derived_1's context. SHOULD WE MAKE THIS VIRTUAL?                                                     
    }

    ..................              

  };            

class Derived_2 :public Base             
   {          
    HRESULT X()            
         {             
        // body of function X() ; full definition given here Derived_2's context.  SHOULD WE MAKE THIS VIRTUAL?
        }              
         ..................           
   };
```

If our intention is to call the function X() generically using a base class pointer, so the decision wheather Derived_1's or Derived_2's definition of X() is called, then is it necessary to make the X() in Derived classes Virtual too.

```
Base * bPtr;
bPtr = new Derived_1(); OR bPtr = new Derived_2(); (Dynamic decision)
bPtr->X()
```

**I feel there is no need to attach the virtual keyword to the definition in Derived classes. Am I right?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can write `virtual` there or not, it doesn't matter. It is implicit (as long as the function really is the same, i.e. has the same signature, as the virtual one in the base class).

Comment: Yes added the public access specifier :) Thanks. I missed it

Comment: @Cornstalks: [No.](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm)

Comment: @phresnel: Thank you, comment rescinded. By the way, I thought I recognized your name from GameDev.net...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions in the derived classes will automatically be virtual if the signature of the function (the type of the arguments and return value, identifiers such as const and virtual) in the derived class is identical to the one in your base class. It doesn't matter whether it is virtual or pure virtual.

So in your example it is not necessary to add virtual for the derived classes.

Comment: Does it make any difference if base class's X() is PURE virtual or VIRTUAL. ?

Comment: Because here the base class's X() is PURE virtual and NOT just VIRTUAL :)

Comment: Yes, I saw that, and as already mentioned the behavior is identical. :-)

Comment: Also 1 more doubt,as you mentioned X() will remain virtual even if I dont attcah Virtual keyword to it in Derived classes, BUT I am getting an error like "cannot instantiate abstract class" if I try to instantiate an object of Derived_1 class. So does it mean the PURE virtual nature of X() has been inherited to Derived class too. ?

Comment: @codeLover: Yes, If you inherit from an abstract class you need to provide definition of **all** pure virtual functions in the derived class or else your derived class becomes a abstract class too.

Comment: The error means that there is one pure virtual function that you didn't implement.

Comment: This example works without any problems:
#include <Windows.h>

class Base 
{
public:  
  virtual HRESULT X()=0; // Now it's pure virtual. 
};


class Derived_1 : public Base  
{   
  HRESULT X()   
  {  
    return 0;
  }
};   

int main()
{
  Base * bPtr;
  bPtr = new Derived_1();
  bPtr->X();
  return 0;
}

Comment: so we made the X() pure virtual just because we don't want to give any definition in base. Oterwise there is no diff between a virtual and pure virtual I feel. Am I right ? :)

Answer (score 3):

C++ has a rule about this: once virtual, always virtual.  Whether or not you say "virtual" in the derived classes doesn't change the fact that `X()` will be virtual.  You can say it or not; `X()` will be virtual in the derived classes anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Once the function is declared virtual in a base class it is not required to declare virtual in the derived class. Sometimes people will declare virtual in the derived class because they feel it's more clear, but it's not a requirement.

Comment: The function is declared as PURE virtual in base class.

Answer (score 2):

A function declared virtual in Base class is virtual in derived class as long as it has the same prototype and not explicitly declared virtual.

You don't need to add a virtual to your derived class function.

**Reference: C++03 10.3 Virtual functions Para 3**

> [Note: a virtual member function does not have to be visible to be overridden, for example,

```
struct B {
    virtual void f();
};
struct D : B {
    void f(int);
};
struct D2 : D {
    void f();
};
```

> the `functionf(int)` in `classD` hides the virtual `functionf()` in its base `classB;` `D::f(int)` is not a virtual function. **However,`f()` declared in `classD2` has the same name and the same parameter list as`B::f()`, and therefore is a virtual function that overrides the function `B::f()`** even though `B::f()` is not visible in `classD2`. ]

Answer (score 2):

**Technically** it is not necessary to write `virtual`.

**Practically** it documents that the function is `virtual`: which means that when inheriting I don't have to check all the way down to the base class to see whether or not it is a `virtual` function. It also underlines the usual caveats: ie call from constructor or destructor at your peril.

**In C++11** there is a better alternative to document "inherited virtuality", the `override` keyword.

```
class Base { public: virtual void method() = 0; };

class Derived: public Base { public: void method() override; };
```

The `override` keyword means that the message *shall* override a base class method (base being transitive here). If there is no base class method overriden, then the code is erroneous and the compiler will yield an error.

Therefore, the presence of the `override` actually makes the difference between a *base* method (first defining a new virtual method in the class) and an *overriding* method. And it is statically checked by the compiler.